# Image of element is square of an element, precisely two maximal ideals satisfying condition.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, field-theory

Say we have $\mathbb{F}_q$ a finite field, $\text{char.} \neq 2$, have $f \in \mathbb{F}_q[x]$, $f \notin \mathbb{F}_q$ be a squarefree element, and let us look at the ring $\mathbb{F}_q[x, \sqrt{f}]$. Have $g$ denotes an irreducible polynomial in $\mathbb{F}_q[x]$ which doesn't divide $f$.

I suppose the following is true.

> If the image of $f$ in $\mathbb{F}_q[x]/(g)$ is a square of some element, there are precisely two maximal ideals $\mathfrak{p}$ of $\mathbb{F}_q[x, \sqrt{f}]$ satisfying $\mathfrak{p} \supset g\mathbb{F}_q[x, \sqrt{f}]$. For these $\mathfrak{p}$,$$\mathbb{F}_q[x]/(g) \overset{\cong}{\to} \mathbb{F}_q[x, \sqrt{f}]/\mathfrak{p}.$$

Is it true or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you are right.

Let $R=F[X,Y]/(Y^2-f)$, where $F$ is a field of characteristic $\ne2$.
Then  $gR=(Y^2-f,g)/(Y^2-f)$ and $R/gR=F[X,Y]/(Y^2-f,g)$.
But we can write $f=h^2+gu$ (in $F[X]$) and then $(Y^2-f,g)=(Y^2-h^2,g)$. Now $$R/gR=F[X,Y]/(Y^2-h^2,g)\simeq (F[X]/(g))[Y]/(Y^2-h^2).$$ But $L=F[X]/(g)$ is a field and by Chinese Remainder Theorem $R/gR\simeq L\times L$ (note that $h\ne0$ in $L$).
This shows exactly what you guessed: there are exactly two prime ideals containing $g$, and moreover, they are maximal. It's also pretty clear now that $R/\mathfrak p\simeq L$ in both cases.